# Many to many mapping with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet with a one-to-many mapping, and I would like to create a new dataframe with a many-to-many mapping in an automated fashion. For example.

Code to make dataframe:

```
names = ['John','Jane','Julia','David']
skills = ['communication, python', 'SQL, Hadoop', 'leadership, project management, excel', 'java']

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':names,'skills':skills})
print(df)
```

| name | skills |
| --- | --- |
| John | communication, python |
| Jane | SQL, Hadoop |
| Julia | leadership, project management, excel |
| David | java |

convert to

| name | skills |
| --- | --- |
| John | communication |
| John | python |
| Jane | SQL |
| Jane | Hadoop |
| Julia | leadership |
| Julia | project management |
| Julia | excel |
| David | java |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()` method and `explode()` method:

```
df['skills']=df['skills'].str.split(',')
df=df.explode('skills',ignore_index=True)
```

Now If You print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    name    skills
0   John    communication
1   John    python
2   Jane    SQL
3   Jane    Hadoop
4   Julia   leadership
5   Julia   project management
6   Julia   excel
7   David   java
```

Comment: You have to do a `.str.strip()` somewhere (after `explode()` for example) to avoid leading whitespaces or change `str.split`.